GDB pretty printers in Almalinux 8
Has anyone managed to set up pretty printers for gdb in Almalinux 8?
printers.py is nowhere to be found when I install  gcc-toolset. I had it working in centos-7 by installing a devtoolset and then in .gdbinit putting something like this:
python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'path-to-devtoolset-prettyprint-for-libstdcxx')
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
end

